# Why is this light-dimming configuration flickering? Why is it not stable?

Tags: triac, dimmer, incandescent, diac

My question is why is this configuration showing an unstable flickering voltage accross the light bulb? Were incorrect capicitance values used?
[image]

Observing the oscilloscope, I note that there is some fluctuation in the voltage accross the lightbulb.

Oscilloscope results:

[image]

[image]

After adjusting the potentiometer and attempting to dim the light, I still get this flickering effect:
[image]

[image]

Note that the blue wave form indicates the amount of trimming of the yellow waveform basically. The blue waveform also "dances" and flickers and does not seem to be stable

Comment: At what time-step does the TRANSIENT analysis run?

Comment: What is the vertical axis for both displayed waveforms and, where on the circuit do those waveforms occur? Can you explain how those waveforms are indicating flicker?

Comment: In a real circuit, this would happen if the light bulb wattage was not large enough. The triac needs a given amount of current to latch otherwise you get the flickering. It might be the same issue in your sim.

Comment: Note that the DIAC is not a "stable" thing ...

Comment: @Andy aka, the vertical axis represents the voltage, the horizontal axis represents time. As mentioned in the question, the yellow waveform represents the mains power, the blue waveform indicates how much of that  has been sliced off to the light bulb. Note that oscilloscope is colour-coded as it references the nodes making it easier to understand.

Comment: @glen_geek Number of Steps: 50 ;  Truncation error-estimation factor: 1 ; Mixed Mode timing tolerance: 1e-009 ;  Minimum Analogue timestep: 1e-006

Comment: `The blue waveform also "dances" and flickers and does not seem to be stable` can you elaborate this? Is it something like the horizontal line (representing zero) is not constant? I'm asking this because I don't see any problem in the waveforms. You are probing the right-hand-side terminal of the bulb and it looks normal. If you worry about the flickering in the simulation that's totally normal because Proteus is not good at simulating switching-based dimming (leading-edge triac dimming, or PWM dimming).

Comment: @Rohat Kilij, if  I live the oscilloscope on, the blue line keeps changing value and waveform. It won't "stay still" as time progresses. The blue line shows how much of the AC power to the light bulb has been cut off. Also, the blue line is "Channel B" on the oscilloscope

Comment: What is the load? It only works on resistive loads and specific types of dimmable LED bulbs that supports this type of dimmer.

Comment: @Saadat the load is 120V, 240 ohm light bulb which is 60W

Comment: When you say oscilloscope, is that in the simulation or on a real circuit? I'm guessing the former, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: What's the hold current of the TRIAC?

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling "flickering" is not real. The numerical analysis that these simulation tools use are resolution-limited and what you are seeing is aliasing effects from that. Basically, they are the rounding errors that are happing under the hood. You can see a similar effect on older computers when you zoom in heavy on a PDF - fine lines will tend to flicker between pixels as the video processor tries to resolve and render the primitives from floating-point math.

For your situation, you can increase the resolution of your time-steps (more steps, smaller time-scale), or you can limit the temporal range of the simulation to only capture the "glitch" that you are looking at (the switching edge).

In practice, this is not an issue - the triac is not really "flickering" and even if it was, the incandescent light would thermal absorb (integrate) this flicker and no one would be the wiser.

Those simulation results look good, BTW.

Comment: I've been struggling to get the correct timing settings but on multisim this circuit seems to work without the flickering. So this is probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the snubber current caused by current through R1,C2
With an incandescent lamp this will not be noticeable,  but with an electronic lamp (eg LED of CFL) it will cause flickering,

For this reason this type of dimmer is not suited to electronic lamps.